# Comparing elements of an array in C to proceed in the removal of element

Tags: c, arrays, combinatorics

I have a problem that I can not figure out (it is probably an easy solution but I can not see it).

The thing is, I have a program that generates all the possible combinations of numbers. The program ask for the size of the set and size of the subsets and generates all the possible combinations accordingly. So far so good ... now ...

I want to write some routines that check for some things in order to eliminate those combinations, one of those routines is the one who checks the array looking to exclude the sequences that exceed a given number of sequenced numbers, for this the program asks for the maximum of numbers in sequences allowed. For example

- Size of the set ? : 10 (stores in n)
- size of the subset?: 10 (stores in k)
- maximum of seq num: 10 (stores in maxp)

the array is called `comb[]` `(integer)` it is initialized as

```
for (i = 0; i < k; i++)
        comb[i] = i;
```

but I have trouble with the routine that exludes certain combinations. The routine is

```
int todel (int comb[], int k)
{

    int i, j, seq;

    for (i = 0, seq = 0; (i+maxp) < k; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;

        for (j = i; j < maxp; j++)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "checkin comb %d with comb %d\n", j, j+1);
            if (comb[j] == (comb[j+1] - 1))
            {
                seq++;
            }
            if (seq >= maxp) return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

if I have a set of 10 a subset of 10 and a max allowed of 10, the program does not need to exlude anything.

But for a set 10 subset 9 and a max allowed of 1 the program should exclude all 10 combinations. But as it is the program is allowing the following combination

> 0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

and it should exclude it because 0,2 does not match the criteria, 2,3 and all thw following does.

Another thing is that if I set the maximum allowed to 0 it takes all combinations as valid instead of none.

I know the fix should not be very hard and I am missing something really dumb.

I hope some insight from you (probably insults too).

Thank you !

Comment: (maxp+i) is about not bothering to enter the for loop if the current index plus the maximum allowed is equal to or exceeds the maximum allowed.

Comment: I really do not understand what is your problem. The posted code doesn't remove element from array. It seems to count (seq) how many sequence with a diff of 1 there are inside of array...

Comment: Yes, my mistake. The routine returns 1 if the combinatoric sequence needs to be "deleted" . i am piping the output to a file and I need to exclude such combinations.

Comment: Indeed, your code return 1 `if (seq >= maxp)`. Then return 1 each time a sequenze of n, n+1, n+2..... is greater then max seq num.

Comment: Yes but the code is not working properly, that is the issue.

With a maxp of 1 in a set of 10 numbers and a subset of 9 (which generates 10 combinations without repetition)

I get

0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

included and it must be excluded because

comparing 0 and 2 is ok, no n and n+1
comparing 2 and 3 is n and n+1 but it is also ok because I allow 1 (maxp)

but then in 3 and 4 the routine should end and return 1 excluding that combination but it does not.

(the code seems to check only position 0 and 1 of the array in that case -that is why the fprinft)

Comment: I added some code that it seems to solve the issue but i am not sure it does it the right way (based on the fprintf added for control)

The code is else seq = 0;  (after the first if structure

The results that the program yield seem to be correct (2 tests only) but I am not sure the code is executing the way I want to yield that result.

Comment: As I answered case 3,4 is not checked because of the inner loop is not executed form `i = 1`. It just execute 1 time for `i=0`.

Comment: btw you are hiding `j`, you have it declared twice in `todel`.

Comment: @LPs I think I solved the issue, the program is working quite well now, thanks for the help. On a side note, not to open another discussion, I have made a simple program to pipe to it from the files generated by the prev program which I can not open into memory since some are 200+ GB in size and in order to run things against the generated things I must pipe, but the program I made reads from stdin, stores into a char[100], do stuff and prints it back to stdout, the thing is I am using the condition while str != NULL . Continues ..

Comment: @LPs the program executes fine untile the last line which then keeps repeating infinitely. I think I should check for eof but the compiler throws a mismatch comparing str to eof. What can/should I do ? . Thanks in advance.